# Need Guided in the Right Direction

Tags: shopify

I have a Shopify site, InkedPlaymats. I sell designs as commission pieces. Right now I just keep track of sale manually and then write up an email each month and quarter telling each of my artists how many pieces they sell. I would rather have a password-protected page that they can enter and see their sales at any given time.

My question is for a point in the right direction to start this. In generic terms how would you go about accomplishing this. I am in school for web development right now and I am trying to push and teach myself new things. I want to teach myself and try to do this, but I really don't know what to start with and/or a smart direction to move in.

thanks guys.

Comment: This seems like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would of course first suggest you get familiar with a lib like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), second i might would suggest you look at using a plug-in like i've created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/MFh36/). it's not very straight forward as I had made that fiddle for myself, but if you want more directions, just holla!

Comment: Too bad I just saw this... I have an App already written and extensively tested that does all Thomas asks for... shame... too late I am sure...

Answer (score 2):

As David mentioned, your first stop should be the Shopify Wiki.

If you're light on actual development experience, this is going to be a little uphill. Start by becoming familiar with one of: Ruby, Python, or PHP. Make sure you know how create basic CRUD-style applications with database connectivity. Ruby is definitely recommended though, because Shopify has an API gem for its web framework, Rails.

Once you've got all of the above covered, here's one possible route:

The artists' work has to be categorized or divided in some way right? You could be using individual collections, for example. Let's assume that you are, for the sake of an example.

So what you need to do is create an interface for choosing specific collections and displaying the sales data associated with those products. You'll need to do four things to accomplish this: (1) Get a list of all collections in the store; (2) Tally the total sales amount for all of the products in each collection, and; (3) Implement an interface for selecting a collection and displaying the sales amount. This is probably the *minimum* feature set you'll need.

So, first you'll need to get a list of all of the collections on the site. Shopify has a method for this, [Custom Collections](http://api.shopify.com/customcollection.html):

```
GET /admin/custom_collections.json
```

This will return an array of your custom collections. It'll look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
  "custom_collections": [
    {
      "title": "IPods",
      "id": 841564295,
    }
  ]
}
```

So now you've got your array. Each element in the array is a collection - and each collection is associated with a particular artist. Second, we'll need to calculate the sales total for each collection. To do this, we'll need a list of orders:

```
GET /admin/orders.json
```

Each order has a `line_items` element, which is an array of all of the products on the order. You're going to need to iterate through each of them, check which collection they belong to, and then add the sale value to a collection-specific variable. Unfortunately, Shopify's API doesn't return back the `collection_id` for a given product. But it does allow you to return a list of products from a given collection.

```
GET /admin/products.json?collection_id=841564295
```

So you'll need to consume this data from Shopify, create a table in your own database, and then look up the product-specific collection_id's yourself. I'll leave the details of all of that for you to figure out :)

But once that's in place, it's relatively straightforward to generate and calculate the running total sales for each collection, just by looping through the products on each order, looking up the their corresponding collections, and then incrementing a collection-specific variable (or database column) with a running total.

Finally, you'll need to build a simple web interface to display a tool to select the collection, and then return the calculated total.

Now, this won't be the final solution - you're going to have to deal with the API call limit (300 per 10 minutes), performance issues, etc. But if you're persistent, you really **can** do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to design a database driven website using PHP and MySql most likely. If you want to do it all yourself. 
Here is a tutorial I found online.
http://www.hosting.vt.edu/tutorials/phpmysql/

Otherwise, you could also look into using a Content Management System or CMS.

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify API is very well documented and has some examples on how to get started writing apps for it. Have a look at http://wiki.shopify.com/Shopify_App_Development for an overview.

Developing for Shopify is easiest in Ruby on Rails as it has the best supported client library (Shopify itself is a Rails app). I'd recommend checking out ruby and Rails tutorials too.